# Hosting Nexus on your own domain as a source for libraries in Maven

Tags: maven, nexus

Why do some companies or projects host nexus on their own domain instead of using Maven Central Repository? Is it related to security? Is this good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several reasons:

- Have a place for the artifacts you build in your company.
- Proxy several external repositories, so that the `settings.xml` only needs to have an entry for the mirror.
- Circumvent proxy/firewall problems that stop developers from using outside repositories directly.

Actually, if you have more than one or two developers, it is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to proxying several external repositories already mentioned, repository manager groups allow you to combine hosted repositories as well into a single source.
Said group can then be organized to return components in an ordered manner (central first, then others, for example).
This makes configuration simpler and allow you to access your internal and external stuff from one place.

Additionally, if you wish to restrict who can access what, you can setup security policies to this affect.  Usually that's not just related to Central, but imagine if you had 3 teams and didn't want them to share each others artifacts.  Then 3 repositories, restrict the security per team but can be same config.

Another benefit is caching.  If you download something, I download something and JF downloads something, that's 3 hits to the internet.  If NXRM downloads it, that's 1 hit then you have it in your intranet.

Note, pretty much everything I just said is not related to just Maven, they're general repository manager perks.